# Созданием Excel файла в PHP через PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

Проблема с созданием Excel файла в PHP через PHPExcel.
На выходе файл не хочет скачиваться и выдаёт ошибку, как на второй картинке.

Вот последние строки кода, в которых файл сохраняется и отдаётся к скачиванию, как мне кажется в них и кроется сама проблема, поскольку если закоментить последнюю строчку кода, то файл скачивается, но с вот такой ошибкой.

```
// Прописываем заголовки для создания файла
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='. $fileNewName .'.xlsx');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

// Сохраняем и отдаём к скачиванию
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image]

Comment: кто такой у вас `$objPHPExcel`?

Comment: ошибка в формировании самого файла, например, формат какой-либо ячейки, содержащий дату, некорректен. попробуйте выгрузить файл всего лишь с одной заполненной текстом ячейкой, будет ли ошибка?